# How do I use --no-deps in a pyproject.toml?

Tags: python, pip, dependency-management, pyproject.toml

I have a `pyproject.toml` file with some python packages.

It has a section like:

```
dependencies = [
    'pandas == 1.4.3',
    'streamlit == 1.11.1',
    ...
]
```

I then usually install these dependencies using

`python -m pip install .[dependencies]`

I need to install a new package that has a conflict in one of its dependencies. I checked, and the "conflict" is superficial - ie. the maintainers of the new package just "forgot" to update the requirements.txt to allow pandas>=1.4.

I can do this by running `python -m pip install {new_package} --no-deps`

But is there any way to do this within the `pyproject.toml` file?